# Drawing a layered tile based map

Tags: c#, dictionary, monogame, tile, tiled

So I'm trying to draw a layered tile based map, as the title says. I have this so far. The tiles i am using are (32, 32). It's currently drawing only 1 type of tile as the whole tile map. When it should be drawing out several different types of tiles to make a map.

```
for (int layers = 0; layers < map.Layers.Count; layers++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < map.Layers[layers].Tiles.Count; i++) {
        int gid = map.Layers[layers].Tiles[i].Gid;

        if (gid != 0) {
            int tileFrame = gid - 1;
            int row = tileFrame / (map.Height / tileHeight);

            float x = (i % map.Width) * map.TileWidth;
            float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)map.Width) * map.TileHeight;

            Rectangle tilesetRec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 32, 32);

            for (int j = 0; j < tileSets.Count; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < tileSets[j].Tiles.Count; k++) {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(tileSets[j].Tiles[k].Image.Texture, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not entirely my code this is someone elses that i have tried to build on apparently it worked for the person for drawing one layer. This is the original code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _map.Layers[0].Tiles.Count; i++) {
    int gid = _map.Layers[0].Tiles[i].Gid;

    // Empty tile, do nothing
    if (gid == 0) {

    } else {
        int tileFrame = gid - 1;
        int row = tileFrame / (_tileset.Height / _tileHeight);

        float x = (i % _map.Width) * _map.TileWidth;
        float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)_map.Width) * _map.TileHeight;

        Rectangle tilesetRec = new Rectangle(_tileWidth * tileFrame, _tileHeight * row, 32, 32);

        spriteBatch.Draw(_tileset, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 32, 32), tilesetRec, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i'm not exactly sure what i'm doing wrong` - Please review [ask] and then [edit] your question to include a *specific* problem.

Comment: Try to debug? This will be fastest then asking question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that for each tile position you seem to be drawing all tiles in all tilesets. The variables `tileFrame`, `row` and `tilesetRec`, which were used to render the specific tile in the original code, are not used in your first snippet.